# Загрузка нового html файла в зависимости от разрешения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как реализовать загрузку индексного файла для разрешений 768, 1024 и тд. в зависимости от разрешения монитора пользователя? Спасибо.

Comment: Извините, а зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko мне это не нужно, это нужно заказчику, сам не понимаю зачем этот геморрой. Если знаете как реализовать, буду благодарен

Comment: 1080 тогда уж..

Comment: @Duoxx что 1080?

Comment: 1080 пикселей..

Comment: Это можно реализовать через AJAX

Comment: @Duoxx да я понимаю что пикселей, я разрешения просто указал..
Спасибо

Comment: [Медиа-запросы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) не подойдут? Т.е. страница одна, но на каждом экране выглядит по-разному.

Comment: @RTK я то понимаю, сам бы на медиа сделал, но так надо заказчику - _- Темболее там просто блок а не полноценная страница

Comment: @SelinCorvin Извиняюсь, за совсем новичка принял) Тогда думаю при загрузке страницы блок будет пустым, затем надо узнавать ширину страницы `document.documentElement.clientWidth` и подгружать HTML в зависимости от ширины через AJAX, а затем добавлять его в этот блок.

Comment: Ну это какая-то белиберда. Если заказчику нужна адаптивность - делайте через медиа-запросы. Если он настаивает - уходите от такого заказчика) А так можно сделать через js `if(document.documentElement.clientWidth>1080) location.href="ваша страница"`

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Спасибо)

Comment: Извращенец, а  не заказчик.....

Answer (score 1):

Заказчик скорее всего хочет адаптивно сделать сайт и придумал такой вот способ :)

```
if ($('body').width() > 1024) {
$("#info").load("max1024.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if(status == "error") {
        $("#info").html("Ошибка: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
} else {
$("#info").load("min1024.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if(status == "error") {
        $("#info").html("Ошибка: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
}
```

и весь контент отображать в блоке с ID = info