# Каждый h3 тэг с новым размером шрифта

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Пожалуйста не предлагайте классы или id. Нужно сделать так, чтобы каждый новый тэг h3 появлялся с новым размером шрифта

Comment: При чём здесь Javascript и jQuery? Неужели для этого не хватит HTML и CSS?

Comment: всмысле появлялсья ?сколько  h3 вам надо ?

Comment: Чем вам не угодили классы или id? Больше подробностей, пожалуйста

Comment: да уж лучше вручную прописать стили через nth-child или ~, чем делать это js'ом

Comment: У вас с автором данного вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839113/Загрузка-нового-html-файла-в-зависимости-от-разрешения#comment1345933_839113 не один на двоих заказчик???  Ему приказал верстать извращение, ну тут приказа не использовать классы и идентификаторы)))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var h3 = document.querySelectorAll('h3');

h3.forEach(function (el, i) { 
  el.style.fontSize = `${(i + 1) * 16}px`;
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Some Text 1</h3>
<h3>Some Text 2</h3>
<h3>Some Text 3</h3>
<h3>Some Text 4</h3>
<h3>Some Text 5</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант c использованием SCSS

Пример (т.к здесь нет поддержки препроцессоров) - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/DmitriyShvanyk/pen/BVQgRM)

```css
$fontSize: 16px;
$heading: 5;
@for $i from 1 through $heading {
  h3:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
     font-size: #{$i * $fontSize}
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Some Text 1</h3>
<h3>Some Text 2</h3>
<h3>Some Text 3</h3>
<h3>Some Text 4</h3>
<h3>Some Text 5</h3>
```